# Socket hangup error while using assert and http in node

Tags: node.js, http, assert

I am trying to create a small http server using node (without using express). Here's the code for the HTTP server

```js
const assert = require('node:assert');
const http = require('node:http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('content-length', 100);
  try {
    res.write('hello world');
  } catch (err) {
    assert(err instanceof Error);
  }
  res.end();
});

server.listen(0, () => {
  http.get({
    port: server.address().port
  });
});
```

When I add a try...catch statement before res.end(), I am getting this error

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:693:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:478:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1344:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:478:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1344:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

The assertion, setHeader and write are key components and cannot be removed.
How do I solve this error without removing them and still be able to assert on any errors on modifying the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try assigning a specific port to the server and then make requests on that port:

```
server.listen(4004, () => {
  http.get({
    port: server.address().port
  });
});
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference. The same error still persists

Comment: i gave a try on the code you just provided it was working fine for me, how long is the request taking?